# Backup folder for 'semi-persistent' files beside Target folder within Maven/Java project? Best practice?

Tags: java, maven, logging, junit

As I understand, within a Maven/Java project the target folder is the standard place to store non-persistent files including log files etc. With e.g. `mvn clean` one can purge it and normally it's not under git.

But working on a JUnit project I would like 'backup' log files from failed runs temporarily. It makes no sense to 'backup' into the target folder, because this 'backups' shouldn't be purged until I finished the failure analysis after some days or weeks.

Otherwise, because it's not a real 'backup', I wouldn't copy those files into a real backup folder and littering backup media.

So I created a separate folder 'errorlogs' beside the target folder, of course, it must be added to .gitignore. I'm wondering if there is a best practice to store such 'semi-persistent' stuff in a kind of standard folder within a Maven/Java project?

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what you mean by `I would like 'backup' log files from failed runs temporarily...`  how long? Failed runs analysing after some days or weeks? Isn't that a little bit late? If a test fails you should investigate the issue asap... ?

Comment: Sure, I create screenshots with every test step. This will be deleted with every mvn clean (hence before every test scenario execution), therefore I 'backup' this screenshots and logs in case of failure outside the target folder. This screenshots and logs are stored in a separate folder to have a failure history over the last days/weeks for analysis purposes. Reason for this: sometimes - especially during the test creation phase - there are non-deterministic failures (e.g. GUI synchro issues). And if the test don't run at production it's not necessary to check it daily.

Comment: Based on what you have written we are talking about integration tests which should run on a CI solution (for example Jenkins) where you can record things like that very easily as well as unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I'm doing automated testing since many years. Mostly it's the case for sure. But there are scenarios were this is not.

Comment: And which are the ones which is it not? You can record information for a time you can define yourself...?

Comment: .. 'for' many years ..

Comment: simple scenario: Jenkins not yet available for administrative reasons. There are not only startups in my world. Sometimes it takes weeks or even months to get the software you want or .. or  ...

Comment: nice guy, thanks for your comments